# Integrating "google-fonts-webpack-plugin" into "vue-webpack" build process

Tags: webpack, vue.js, google-fonts

I'm currently trying to integrate static offline fonts into my Webpack build process. I'm using the [`vue-webpack`](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) build process as the basis of my build process.

I found this nice library [`google-fonts-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/gabiseabra/google-fonts-webpack-plugin) which provides all the font files and a single CSS file.

I integrated it into the existing `vue-webpack` prod build like this:

```
plugins: [
  // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': env
  }),

  new GoogleFontsPlugin({
    fonts: [
      { family: 'Roboto', variants: [ '300', '400', '400italic', '500' ] }
    ]
  }),

  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  [ ... ]
```

The resulting files of the google-fonts-webpack-plugin seem to be completely independent of the otherwise regularly generated files. This means, the resulting `fonts.css` is not part of the versioned CSS file. In the `dist/` folder, `fonts.css` and a directory `fonts/` appear, but they are not even in the `static/` folder as everything else.

How can I hook this library into the regular CSS/font build process of `vue-webpack`, so that `fonts.css` ends up in the versioned CSS file and the font files in the `static/fonts` directory?

Comment: Maybe you can just import or require it in one of your .js files with. This works the same way.

Comment: The plugin downloads the files and adds it to the output. The files don't exist beforehand, but only after the build, so I cannot require it in the source files.. I could manually download the font files and require it but then the whole point of the webpack plugin is undercut.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll get this plugin to work with the Vue webpack build. You can add some configuration to put the fonts and css where you want, for example:

```
new GoogleFontsPlugin({
  fonts: [
    { family: 'Roboto', variants: [ '300' ] }
  ],
  path: "../src/assets/",
  filename: "../src/assets/fonts.css"
}),
```

But the way the plugin is written, you can't get the files before the file loaders try to access the css file and throw an error. You can also put the fonts directly in the `./dist` folder which is close, but the plugin writes a path in the the `index.html` with a absolute path (i.e. `/dist/static/fonts/`), and there doesn't seem to be a way to change that without changing the source code.

You might have better luck using something like Gulp to download the files and css into the assets folder before running build. (maybe: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-google-webfonts)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know any plugin for webpack which might work with the vue-webpack build? I don't like the idea to download the files and add them to the source folder or integrate Gulp into my build process.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the npm module [typeface-roboto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeface-roboto) and then import index.css from that module.

Answer (score 0):

using "webpack": "^3.10.0" . / node v8.9.3 , "vue": "^2.5.13"
and  "google-fonts-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.4",

webpack.dev.conf.js

```
  plugins: [
  ...
        // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.dev.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ]),
    new GoogleFontsPlugin({
            fonts: [
                { family: "Source Sans Pro" },
                { family: "Lato", variants: ["400", "300", "700", "900"] },
                { family: "Raleway", variants: ["400", "500", "600"] }
      ]
    })
```

and in  main.css, use the font-family as is...

```
        .header-text {
          font-family: Raleway;
          font-weight: 300;
          text-transform: capitalize;
          font-size: 35px;
          color: rgb(124, 112, 102);
          letter-spacing: 2px;
          margin-bottom: 30px;
          margin-left: 5px;
          margin-top: 0px;
        }
```

NOW in staging, production distribution , need to add an outputDir in the

webpack.prod.conf.js

```
        new GoogleFontsPlugin({
                fonts: [
                    { family: "Source Sans Pro" },
                    { family: "Lato", variants: ["400", "300", "700", "900"] },
                    { family: "Raleway", variants: ["400", "500", "600"] }
          ],
          outputDir: "dist/fonts"
        }),
```

the file structure adter build will be the following

[image: webpack build file structure]

beside the static folder, you get :

- a font folder with all the fonts from googlefonts
- a fonts.css file with the @font-face{font-family.... and urls relative to the font folder
- a fonts.css.map